# How do I change a property's value based on a conditional in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I would like to change the value of a property if it is a certain value.  In C#  I would write:

```
if(x=="NotAllowed")
  x="CorrectedValue;
```

This is what I have so far, please don't laugh:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <BranchName>BranchNameNotSet</BranchName>
  </PropertyGroup>

///Other targets set BranchName

 <Target Name="CheckPropertiesHaveBeenSet">
    <Error Condition="$(BranchName)==BranchNameNotSet" Text="Something has gone wrong.. branch name not entered"/>
      <When Condition="$(BranchName)==master">
        <PropertyGroup>
          <BranchName>MasterBranch</BranchName>
        </PropertyGroup>
      </When>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that using `Condition` on `Property`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BranchName>BranchNameNotSet</BranchName>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CheckPropertiesHaveBeenSet">
  <!-- If BranchName equals 'BranchNameNotSet' stop the build with error-->
  <Error Condition="'$(BranchName)'=='BranchNameNotSet'" Text="Something has gone wrong.. branch name not entered"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Change BranchName value if BranchName equals 'master' -->
    <BranchName Condition="'$(BranchName)'=='master'">MasterBranch</BranchName>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Target>
```

#### Info on `When` and `Choose`:

> The Choose, When, and Otherwise  elements are used together to provide a way to select one section of code to execute out of a number of possible alternatives.
>
> Choose elements can be used as child elements of Project, When and Otherwise elements.

In your code sample, you use `When` without `Choose` and within a target, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks madgnome, i've given it to you because you made it explicit that the propertygroup goes inside my target

Answer (score 3):

this sets BranchName to the string 'CorrectedValue' if it's value equals 'NotAllowed':

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <BranchName Condition="'$(BranchName)'=='NotAllowed'">CorrectedValue</BranchName>
</PropertyGroup>
```