# MSBuild meta-properties - how to retrieve a property value where the property name is a composition of other properties?

Tags: msbuild, properties

I'd like to be able to write the below, but I can't in MSBuild:

```
<Target Name="SetDynamicPropertyValues"> 
   <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetHost>$($(Target-Environment)-Host)</TargetHost>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

This is easily done in NAnt using the [property::get-value function](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/property.get-value%28System.String%29.html). The answer to an earlier question shows an [approach using the Condition attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044480/how-do-i-change-a-propertys-value-based-on-a-conditional-in-msbuild).

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild processes property names once. To do that kind of feature it must call the preprocessing several times. I think it would be better to use a Condition-based approach.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetHost Condition="'$(Target-Environment)'=='Env1'">Host_1</TargetHost>
   <TargetHost Condition="'$(Target-Environment)'=='Env2'">Host_2</TargetHost>
   <TargetHost Condition="'$(TargetHost)'==''">DefaultHost</TargetHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```